# Linux native executable does not consist of proper symbol information

Tags: java, elf, debug-symbols, objdump

I am using Excelsior Jet (A java to native compiler) to compile a Java application into a native executable. I have been successful in doing that. The standalone executable runs properly on my system. Now, I wanted to instrument the execution of this native executable using Intel's PIN Tool (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads). Pintool is an instrumentation tool developed by Intel. It is used by architecture/system designers to gain insights into the execution of the program.

Executing the program with pin-tool is giving following error :
Source/pin/elfio/img_elf.cpp: ProcessSectionHeaders: 611: assertion failed: shs[i].sh_entsize == sizeof(DYNREC)

I disassembled the executable using the objdump utility on Linux. It only consisted of one .text section. Other sections like main, etc. were missing.
I think the native executable created does not consist of proper symbols which are needed to display such information.

Is there any way to add symbol information to the executable or is there any other way to sanitize an executable created by a third party tool?

Comment: You're using a commercial tool to create the executable code. Their manual seems to hint that compiling with debugging information is possible. You should address your question at their customer technical support.

Answer (score 0):

I work for the company that makes the tool in question.

Problem is, Java apps have so many classes and methods that symbolic information won't fit into the standard formats. This is true at least for the Windows PE format. So we had to write our own loader that uses a proprietary format.